# MS SQL case statements and referring to results

Tags: sql-server

This may be quite a dumb question for somebody who has been using SQL for around 12 years but...

In the accounting database that I use, all numbers are stored as positive numbers......in other words the net value of an invoice is stored as a positive number and so is the net value of a credit note......the transactions 'TranType' is used to differentiate between the two ('Inv' for invoice, 'CRN' for credit note), so, whenever I have to write a report that uses transactional data, I always have to write a case statement...

```
case when TranType = 'INV' then Net else NetVal *-1 end as 'Net'
```

...I'm wondering if there is any way to create a column within a specific report that I can refer to without having to retype the case statement over and over again (ie so I can refer to 'Net' which gives the results of the case statement)?

thanks,

Darren

Comment: Could you create a view?

Comment: Sounds like a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx?ppud=4), as shown by Szymon.

Comment: Please don't use single quotes to surround aliases - some forms of this syntax are deprecated and, even where it's not, it makes it look like a string literal. In cases where you *need* to escape identifiers (such as poorly chosen reserved words, invalid characters, etc.) you should use `[square brackets]`.

Comment: @HABO - computed columns look very interesting indeed! ...as this is a proprietary database (not one i've created myself) I decided to go for a view so as not to interfere with the structure

Comment: @JazzyJ - Yes, I've gone for a view in this case

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. You can create a column like that in your `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE`:

```
[TrueTotal]  AS (case when TranType = 'INV' then Net else NetVal *-1 end)
```

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
    [TranType] varchar(3) not null,
    Net decimal(20,2) not null,
    NetVal decimal(20,2) not null,
    [TrueTotal]  AS (case when TranType = 'INV' then Net else NetVal *-1 end)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've gone for a view in this case as this is an 'off the shelf' accounting database and I do not want to interfere with the structure.

The concept of computed columns is something that I've not come across before. I think I will investigate them further as I think they could be very useful to me.

Thanks to all.

Darren